# Sum of column depending on values

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can you guys let me know how to make a query that output the sum of amount based on column values(order, Continent and Country)? Also, I want to show all Continent values as unique value (North America)

Example table,

```
ID    Code   Continent       Country          amount
----------------------------------------------------
1       1     North America   NULL               NULL
2       1     America         USA                10
3       1     NA              USA                10
4       1     Unknown         USA                10
5       2     North America   NULL               NULL
6       2     America         Canada             15
7       2     NA              Canada             15  
8       2     Unknown         Canada             15
9       3     North America   NULL               NULL
10      3     America         Mexico             20
11      3     NA              Mexico             20  
12      3     Unknown         Mexico             20
```

Output

```
ID  Code  Continent       Country       SumAmount
----------------------------------------------
1     1    North America     USA            30
2     2    North America     Canada         45
3     3    North America     Mexico         60
```

I have tried to approach it like

```
select ID, Code, case when Continent != 'North America' then Continent = 'North America' end as Continent, Country, sum(Amount) as SumAmount
from Table group by ID, Continent, Country
```

or maybe I need to make a query like this and work with this query below?

```
select ID, Code, Continent, Country, sum(Amount) as SumAmount
from Table where Continent !='North America'
```

But it is not working. How should I do this?

I appreciate for any other approaches. It would be better than mine

Comment: First you should fix that truly horrible design. There should be a continent table with the continent names and abbreviations, a country table withe country names and abbreviations referencing the continent table and then a table for the numbers referencing the country table. Relational tables aren't spread sheets!

Comment: Sorry for all. Those are simple mistake and I edited.

Comment: @stickybit We don't know enough to decide if the design is horrible. It could be a data warehouse. It could be a table given to OP by their boss or teacher. I start every semester with tables like this because students have not yet learned joins or foreign keys.

Comment: @nicomp: That design sure *is* horrible, very, very horrible and everybody with a 101 in *relational* databases can see that.

Comment: @nicomp nah, that's a bad data set, and I disagree that anyone should suggest to beginner students on day 1 that this kind of data structure is even possible. A better starting example to avoid fear of joins is to repeat `North America` on each row. At least that has a logical progression from flat to relational.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The awkward design here (relations with no real indication of such other than the shared `Code` column) is going to lead to suboptimal queries like this

```
DECLARE @ContinentToReport varchar(32) = 'North America';

;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT Code FROM dbo.TableName 
  WHERE Continent = @ContinentToReport 
    AND Country IS NULL
)
SELECT ID = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY x.Code), 
       x.Code, 
       Continent = @ContinentToReport, 
       t.Country, 
       SumAmount = SUM(t.amount)
  FROM dbo.TableName AS t
  INNER JOIN x ON t.Code = x.Code
  WHERE t.Country IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY x.Code, t.Country
  ORDER BY x.Code;
```

Output (though I made a guess at what `ID` means and why it's different then the `ID` and the source, and I find the `Continent` column is kind of redundant since it will always be the same):

| ID | Code | Continent | Country | SumAmount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | North America | USA | 30 |
| 2 | 2 | North America | Canada | 45 |
| 3 | 3 | North America | Mexico | 60 |

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=80386eb7dcc6baed353daa20edad3764)

Comment: Thanks for your help! What should I do if Code is not number something 'A', 'B' and 'C'? I tried it but it shows nothing with the same code.

Comment: @Oasis can you create a [fiddle](https://sqlblog.org/fiddle), like I did, or [borrow mine](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=80386eb7dcc6baed353daa20edad3764) and _show_ what you mean and update your desired results, instead of trying a word problem? (Also, don't oversimplify your problem ... if your codes are letters, why are they numbers in your question?)

Comment: Here is a fiddle [link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=33aac989577fbbd4d96568bb07c8f2bc) I borrowed your format.  I have more complicated data but I wanted to work on it step by step from easy steps. My codes are written as numbers but it is not 'orderable' 


This is something similar I want to try and I once again realize how my design was super terrible. This honestly makes it as a different question. I tried to minimize my original data and it made it worse. Also, I really appreciate for your help again.

Comment: @Oasis Basically you wanted to order by ID instead of code, but this won't work if you can't rely on _either_ column for ordering. You need _something_ to tell SQL Server that `Red` comes before `Blue`. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=37a65c111723fbdaa05dca38446a6c0d

Comment: @Oasis if red, blue, etc. are _known_ then you could say `ORDER BY CASE Code WHEN 'Red' THEN 1 WHEN 'Blue' THEN 2 ELSE 3 END`.

Comment: Thank you So much. It helps a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest query which returns the correct result seems to be something like this

```
select row_number() over (order by Code) ID, 
       Code, 
       'North America' Continent, 
       Country, 
       sum(amount) SumAmount
from dbo.TableName
where Country is not null
group by Code, Country
order by Code;
```

[dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=78b9c579715b84b4d4fa1f90aa36144f)

Comment: I inferred that there are other continents in the table; they just want the rows belonging to North America in the result. (If the whole table is North America, why bother having any row that says so?)